# How to get today - “6 months” date in PySpark(SQL)

Tags: python, apache-spark, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the table which is updated every day. I use this table for analysis. I want to have a static window of 6 months data as input for analysis.

I know I can make a filter like this in SQL to have 6 months data every time I run the code.

```
date >= dateadd(mm, -6, getdate())
```

Can somebody suggest how I can carry on the same action in PySpark. I can only think of this:

```
df.filter(col("date") >= date_add(current_date(), -6)))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 14):

`date_add` will add or subtract a number of days, in this case use `add_months` instead:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.filter(F.col("date") >= F.add_months(F.current_date(), -6)))
```